# broadcast secret code with permission

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

I want to be able to broadcast this intent

```
<receiver android:name="GsdBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.htc.permission.APP_DEFAULT">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />
           <data android:scheme="android_secret_code" android:host="3424" />
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

so far this is how i'm trying to launch it

```
adb shell am broadcast -W -a android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE -d android_secret_code://3424
```

but I haven't succeed with that, I think the problem comes with the permission, do you know how I can deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tried that in Java, but it works fine via adb. However, you have to run it with superuser.

```
adb shell "su -c 'am broadcast -a android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE -d android_secret_code://0011'"
```

Tested on **rooted** Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 4.3.
I used 0011 secret code (3424 is for HTC devices).